# Rails: How to add scope to pg_search with location search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scope

I have two models, `Location` and `Basic`, I'm using [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem, how do I add scope to my `pg_search_scope` with **geocoder** `near` method or if there's another method to do so?

`Location` model has the latitude and longitude columns.

In my controller I'm able to do this:

```
# this allows me to search near the Location model
@business = Location.near(params[:loc], 15)

# this searches through the pg_search_scope
@term = Basic.search(params[:q])

#I'm trying to combine @business and @term
```

And with `Basic` model I have this:

```
pg_search_scope :search, :against => [:first_name, :last_name], 
  :associated_against => {
    :services => [:service, :description]
  },
  :using => {
    :tsearch => {:disctionary => "english" }
  }
```

I'd like to combine both `@business` and `@term` into one `(@search)` Is this possible?

Thanks

++++++++++++++++

So in my `Basic` model:

```
class Basic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location

  has_many :services, as: :servicable

  pg_search_scope :search, :against => [:first_name, :last_name], 
    :associated_against => {
      :services => [:service, :description]
    },
    :using => {
      :tsearch => {:disctionary => "english" }
    }

end
```

So in my model, I have services that is linked with basic. So when I search a name or a service results pop out. But I'm trying to only display results near a certain location that a user inputs, thats why I have a `location_id` column in my `Basic` table.

This is my `Location` model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basics
  geocoded_by :new_address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :new_address_changed?
  def gmaps4rails_address
    :new_address
  end
  def new_address_changed?
    attrs = %w(street city state)
    attrs.any?{|a| send "#{a}_changed?"}
  end  
end
```

So I'm trying to chain the methods. Ideally the application would search all nearby results first, and then search the terms that matches within the nearby results, then display only those that are applicable.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `@business` and `@term` as well as describe what you want `@search` to be?

Comment: @andrewliu Could you also specify relations between `Location` and `Basic` models?

Comment: Your example for fetching those is from two different classes with no relations between. By that I mean setting `@term` doesn't depend on the results from `@business` so combining that into a single scope is probably not what you're looking for - but I could be wrong. Are you trying to create one array of results based on the values in `@term` and `@business`?

Comment: @skalee I edited my answer, hopefully it helps?

Comment: @izuriel yes, I'm trying to create one array, that applies to both search fields I have. I updated my question if it makes more sense

Comment: @screenmutt I updated my question. `@business` and `@term` are completely separate from each other. But because these two models are associated somehow, I'd like to chain the methods `near` and `search` so that when user types in a term and a location, the correct result will poop out

Comment: What type of order are you looking for - is it not enough to just join the two result lists? Do you need a specific sort mechanism? If you know you're going to use all the values fetched from both results what's wrong with `@business.load + @term.load`?

Comment: @izuriel adding it like that won't work, because it will search all terms and all locations. But I only want to search the terms within the location specified. `pg_search` is good for my application because its an easy way to implement full-text searching.

Comment: I think you missed it... `@business` is your near search and `@term` is your `pg_search` - Did I miss something? You're joining multiple searches, or do you mean to search only those `Basic` items that are also near a certain location?

Comment: Perhaps try `merge` like `Basic.search(params[:query]).includes(:location).merge(Location.near(params[:loc], 15)`

Comment: @izuriel hmm i thought it would work, but I'm getting an error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Static#search` and then the error is `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "locations"` and a bunch of other line codes.

Comment: Change the include to `:locations`

Comment: @izuriel dangit, its still giving me the same errors when changing it to plurarl.

Comment: I always user `includes` before any other call, if you can do that try it, otherwise try replacing `includes` with `joins`.

Comment: @izuriel yes it works! thank you!!! I'm not sure why the includes wouldn't work? But joins do work. Would you like to answer this question so I can send you some points? Thank you!

Comment: @izuriel also, I just realized that my id doesn't show up? when I have joins, I only have location_id (from `Basic`) and id (from `Location`), but no id (from `Basic`). I need the id from Basic so I can create a link to a page.

Comment: @andrewliu I'll draft up an answer when I help you solve this issue, I'll look into finding out about lost IDs.

Comment: @andrewliu `includes` and `joins` *can* result in the same thing but don't have to. `includes` forces objects to be created for the included association, but no `JOINS`. `joins` forces an `INNER JOIN` on the association but does not include it in the `SELECT` (and creates no objects). It is legitimate, to combine the two, forcing a `JOIN` with eager loading. But be aware of the difference between `INNER` and `OUTER JOIN`. `includes` does the latter. I suggested something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322580/optimize-difficult-query-possibly-with-squeel/19527607#19527607)

Comment: @izuriel thank you so much for your help. Let me know when you find lost id solution, and then I'll put up another bounty for your answer. Right now I had to get the ID from looping `<%= getID = Basic.find_by_first_name_and_last_name(s.first_name, s.lastName) %>`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want are the `Location`s that are near `params[:loc]` and associated with `Basic`s that match the term `params[:q]`. If that interpretation is wrong, all the rest of this will be wrong.

To do this purely in the database, you need to join the `locations` table using the conditions added by the `near` scope with the `basics` and `services` tables using the conditions added by `pg_search_scope`. Unfortunately, I haven't found any way to use `pg_search_scope` with arbitrary joins to other tables, so I don't know of a simple query-based solution to this. But if your `@business` and `@term` results are relatively small, you can just do the join in ruby. After your controller code:

```
@matching_businesses = @business & @term.map(&:location)
```

There are other ways to do that, but the idea is to find the unique set of `Location`s between those in your `@business` results and those associated with the `Basic`s in your `@term` results. Here's another way that maybe reads more clearly:

```
@matching_businesses = @business.select do |business|
  @term.any? { |basic| business.basics.include?(basic) }
end
```

If that isn't performant enough, you'll probably need to write your own queries or read through the `pg_search_scope` implementation to figure out how to make it support arbitrary joins.